# BitcoinCore 25.1 won't launch (Windows 10.0.19045)

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, bitcoin.conf

I updated BitcoinCore (v19 to 25.1) and get this error at launch:

```
Error: Error reading configuration file: conf cannot be set in the configuration file; use includeconf= if you want to include additional config files
```

My database and config file are in another folder (C:\BTC_BitcoinCore).
But having done a clean install this shouldn't matter.

I uninstalled the old version, cleaned the directories, cleaned the registry, [repaired Windows according to this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on/95a62b0a-425a-4684-9aa1-a3d693417cf9?page=1), restarted, reinstalled BitcoinCore, given security access to the whole folder to everyone and unchecked the read-only box, but the error still is there.

I probably missed an important thing about the config file (I left it as per the install, and maybe that's the problem ?).

I really have not another idea left, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit : an older bitcoin.conf file in Appdata that I missed somehow.

Edit: Thanks for pointing me to the right solution, Antoine !